# find a single char in a string

Tags: c++

I have a string containing either "0123456789 ?". I would like to

```
- if first char is not ' ' or '?' and the rest is " ", return the first char
- if last char is not ' ' or '?' and the rest is " ", return the last char
- if the string is only " ", return -1
- and else, return -2
```

I found several solutions but none of them satisfy me in term of speed and nice coding.
Could someone that think of a nice and elegant solution, share it to me ?!

Thank You

Comment: Post the best solution you came up with and we'll help you make it pretty for the ball.

Comment: Looks like homework to me. You can tag it as such and we'll still give help you just need to show what you have tried first.

Comment: @CharlesBeattie [The homework tag is deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) so it is correct that the OP didn't include it

Comment: And if the string is empty?  (-2, I suppose.)  And for the third case, does this mean a string of exactly one space, of one or more spaces, or of one or more white space?

Comment: Strange task - it should returns both char and integer (yes, I know about conversion int to char). But it may cause problems if chars will be treated as unsigned chars.

Comment: @AlexG.P. It shoult return the integer value corresponding to the char... but this is not a problem.

Comment: @AlexG.P. Maybe he should convert the character to `unsigned char` before returning it?  (That way, the integer values would clearly be out of band, rather than being ambiguous.)

Comment: @Jav and what if the integer value corresponding to the char is -1 or -2?

Comment: @CharlesBeattie. This is not a homework

Comment: @LuchianGrigore. My solution is with str::find_first_of("0123456789") and str::find_last_of("0123456789") and comparing them to str::npos, soustract them and see if it is 0, and if so, see if it is the first char or the last char... but ... well... I find this very ugly :-/

Comment: @JamesKanze. The string is not empty (but taking it into account seems legit and -2 is a good return value). In the third case, there may be more than one ' '.

Comment: @JamesKanze. The chars can be ' ', '?' or a digit : 0 to 9.

Comment: @CharlesBeattie: Apparently homework questions are no [longer appreciated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) and the homework tag deprecated and banned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this?

```
stringtest(string &s)
{
    if(string.length()<1)
    return -2
    std::string begin(' ?');
    if(begin.find(s.front())>1)
    //test if first character of s is in begin
    {
        unsigned found = s.find_first_not_of(' ',1)
        //checks if there are any other char then ' ' after the first char
        if(found >s.length())
        return s.at(0);
    }
    else if(begin.find(s.back())>1)
    //test if last character of s is in begin
    {
        unsigned found = s.find_last_not_of(' ',s.length()-1);
        //checks if there are any other char then ' ' before the last char
        if(found !=std::string::npos)
        return s.at(s.length()-1);
    }
    if(s.length()==1 && s.front()== ' ')
    return -1
    else return -2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like your usual `if ... else if ... ... else ...`
chain.  Some functions which might help:

- `std::string::front()` and `std::string::back()` to get the
  first or the last character,
- `std::find_if` to check for white space.  If this function
  returns the end iterator, the value wasn't found.

If you can use C++11 (If you're a student, you probably can; if
you work in industry, you probably can't.), the most elegant 
solution for the `std::find_if` is probably a lambda.  So: all
of the string except the first character is white space would
be:

```
std::find_if(
    s.begin() + 1,
    s.end(),
    []( char ch ) { return ! isspace( static_cast<unsigned char>( ch ) ); }
    ) == s.end();
```

For all but the first, or for all, just change the iterators.

Just don't forget to check for an empty string before using
`front()` or `back()`, or doing any arithmetic on an iterator.

Comment: In term of speed, creating an iterator is not the best choice ... in my opinion

Comment: @Jav If you care about speed, you should measure it and see if your iterator hypothesis holds.

Comment: @Jav Compared to what?  If the length of the string may vary, and you need to call `isspace` on each element, you're going to have to iterate through it.